# (De-) Serializing Complex Class Hierarchies

Tags: json, inheritance, serialization, flutter, dart

I currently try to serialize and deserialize the class model of my app but I can't find a nice way to do it.

The problem is that some components have member variables with an abstract type (Model's `root` member has the abstract type `Super`). When deserializing this, I have no way of knowing, whether `root` is of type `ConcreteA` or `ConcreteB`. How do I solve this problem nicely?

```dart
class Model {
  Super root;

  Model({this.root});
}

abstract class Super {
  int superProp;

  Super({this.superProp});
}

class ConcreteA extends Super {
  int aConcrete;

  ConcreteA({this.aConcrete, int superProp}) : super(superProp: superProp);
}

class ConcreteB extends Super {
  ConcreteB({int superProp}) : super(superProp: superProp);
}

void main() {
  var modelA = Model(root: ConcreteA(aConcrete: 1, superProp: 2));
  // somehow serialize and deserialize without code repetition in fromJSON
}
```

Comment: Consider object composition instead of inheritance. That will make deserialization a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks but this is not an option for me for various reasons. Any other ideas?

Comment: I might misunderstand your intentions, but have your considered using [built_value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) which allows some fields to be annotated with `@nullable` making you able to have it all in one class and check if the fields are `null` before operating with them?

Comment: If you want to use only JSON, then you should know that JSON does not support type inheritance. This is because JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help! Putting everything in one class is not an option because my model is way more complex than the model above. I thought there might be a package that does something similar to Jackson for Java here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance
For now, I manually added a 'type' field that helps me parse the JSON correctly. In the future I might just use XML.